# Angular 2 own Class Decorator to access Dependency Injection Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a class decorator `TopicClass` which adds a property and a function to the decorated component. The function must access a injected Service. **How do I do that?**

Here is what tried unsuccessfully:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
@TopicClass('home')
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private topicService: TopicService) { }
}
```

I cannot access the injected Service through the inserted function `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
export function TopicClass(title: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    const original = target;

    function construct(constructor, args) {
      const c: any = function () {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
      }
      c.prototype = constructor.prototype;

      const newInstance = new c();
      newInstance['topic'] = new Topic(title, '');

      newInstance['ngAfterViewInit'] = () => {
        newInstance['topicService'].setTopic(newInstance['topic']);
      }
      return newInstance;
    }

    const ctor: any = (...args) => {
      console.log("Service: " + original.prototype.topicService);
      return construct(original, args);
    };

    ctor.prototype = original.prototype;
    return ctor;
  }
}
```

The problem is `newInstance['topicService']` is undefined.

I have set up a simple Angular project for testing: 
https://github.com/ptea/angular-class-decorator-test

https://github.com/ptea/angular-class-decorator-test/blob/master/src/app/services/topic.service.ts

I also tried to reproduce the problem with a simple TypeScript program, which works as intended:

```
newInstance['printStreet'] = () => {
  console.log(`printFirstnameStreet: ${newInstance['firstname']}, ${newInstance['street']}`);
}
```

https://github.com/ptea/angular-class-decorator-test/blob/master/dashboard.ts

**Any ideas/solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the `TopicService` is undefined is because it was never injected into the component. With your current decorator it is redefining the constructor of the `HomeComponent` to be a constructor that has no arguments. This is messing up Angular's DI and so the `TopicService` is not injected when the Component is instantiated.

The best way I can think of to accomplish what you want is to not modify the constructor of the `HomeComponent` and instead tap into the `ngOnInit` method instead. The ngOnInit method is an ideal candidate because it is called once per the component's lifecycle and it has a fixed number of  parameters, 0, which makes it easy to wrap inside another function. You can similarity do this with the `ngAfterViewInit` function to use the service when desired.

Here is how you could modify the `TopicClassDecorator` to acheive your desired result:

```
export function TopicClass(title: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {

    let targetNgOnInit = target.prototype.ngOnInit;
    target.prototype.ngOnInit = function (){
      this.topic = new Topic(title, 'subTitle');

      if(targetNgOnInit){
        targetNgOnInit.apply(target);
      }
    }

    let targetNgAfterViewInit = target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit;        
    target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit = function (){
      this.topicService.setTopic(this.topic);

      if(targetNgAfterViewInit){
        targetNgAfterViewInit.apply(target);
      }
    }

    return target;
  }
}
```

[Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/crBm7D70VLRYOrlwYCxx) of everything working together.

Comment: I was expecting the arguments from the target constructor instead of empty. Your code does work when the 'return target' is removed.

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with the following solution without overriding the ngOnInit function:

```
export function TopicClass(title: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    target.prototype.topic = new Topic(title);

    let targetNgAfterViewInit = target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit;        
    target.prototype.ngAfterViewInit = function () {
      this.topicService.setTopic(this.topic);

      if(targetNgAfterViewInit){
        targetNgAfterViewInit.apply(target);
      }
    }
  }
}
```